# WES7 problems after installing security update

Tags: windows-7

I'm configuring a "Windows Embedded Standard 7" install image, for an embedded application. Because of storage limits, "**Internet Explorer 8 Browser**" is not installed in the image, but "**Internet Explorer 8 Engine and Display**" and "**Internet Explorer 8 Foundation**" are.

After a fresh installation of the image, everything is working perfect. I can run *inetcpl.cpl* and the "Internet Properties" window opens. If I run *services.msc* the "Services" window opens on the "Extended" tab, and I can see all the services with an description to the left.

However, after installing "Security Update for Internet Explorer 8 for Windows Embedded Standard 7 (KB2847204)", I can suddenly not open the "Internet Properties" window anymore, if I run *inetcpl.cpl* nothing happens. When I open the "Services" window, the "Extended" tab is completely empty and if I click on the "Standard" tab the following error message is shown:

```
Unable to download.

Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.

Please try again later
```

I can then uninstall KB2847204 and everything works perfect, like before.

So far I have tried to run the *sfc /scannow* command but that did not work.

As I'm not normally working on the Windows platform, I need advice on how to debug this problem..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the exact same problem with a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (SP1). The description for MS13-038 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2847204) stated that the latest IE cumulative security update (MS13-037/KB2829530) should be applied as well. It wasn't on my system and after applying the cumulative update, the "services.msc" functionality was fully restored.